# How to get the selected text of options in multiple select?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the selected option in multiple select, I can get the value in the form of an array, but I can't get the text of the option.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#sizeAddCategory').change(function(e) {
    var selected = $(e.target).text();
    console.log("selected " + selected);
    $('#textAreaAddCategory').val(selected.join(','));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
  <label for="sel1">Select Sizes (hold ctrl or shift (or drag with the mouse) to select more than one):</label>
  <br/>
  <select required class="form-control" id="sizeAddCategory" multiple>
    
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
    <option value="4">four</option>
    
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-3">
  <label for="name">Selected Sizes</label>
  <br/>
  <textarea required disabled rows="4" class="form-control" id="textAreaAddCategory"></textarea>
</div>
```

On `$(e.target).text()`, I am getting all the options text, I need the text of only selected options, so I can display it in the `textarea`.

Comment: selects have a selectedIndex property, so the selected text is $(e.target).text()[target.selectedIndex]

Comment: Error: target is not defined

Comment: yes because your target is on e ... so e.target.selectedIndex

Comment: Any errors in the console?  I've converted the code *as provided* to a snippet, which shows a console error.

Comment: @RenéDatenschutz `.text()` will be a string, so `.text()[0]` will be the first letter of that string, not a selected index.  For a *single* select (not multi) you could use `$(e.target).find("option").eq(e.target.selectedIndex).text()` - but seems a bit overkill for just `$(this).val()`

Comment: @RenéDatenschutz you mean like this - `var selected = $(e.target).text()[e.target.selectedIndex];` it isnt displaying anything

Comment: @ShahRukh you need to stop using `.text()` completely :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.text()` on a `select` will give the text of the control - i.e. all of the options, not just the selected ones.

To get the selected *text* (not value as you pointed out you can already get), you can use:

```
$(this).find("option:checked").map((i,e)=>$(e).text()).toArray();
```

Here, `$(this).find("option:checked")` will give you the `option` elements that have been selected while the `.map` will return the `.text()` for each of those values into a jquery array, with `.toArray()` to convert to a normal js array.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#sizeAddCategory').change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).find("option:checked").map((i,e)=>$(e).text()).toArray();
    console.log("selected", selected);
    $('#textAreaAddCategory').val(selected.join(','));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
  <label for="sel1">Select Sizes (hold ctrl or shift (or drag with the mouse) to select more than one):</label>
  <br/>
  <select required class="form-control" id="sizeAddCategory" multiple>
    
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
    <option value="4">four</option>
    
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-3">
  <label for="name">Selected Sizes</label>
  <br/>
  <textarea required disabled rows="4" class="form-control" id="textAreaAddCategory"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the target that you're defining is in the select tag. Instead of using:

```
$('#sizeAddCategory').change(function(e) {
```

use:

```
$('.option-category').click(function(e) {
```

and add a class in the options:

```
<option value="{{$size->id}}" class="option-category">{{$size->name}}</option>
```

Comment: if i concatenate it in textarea it will work, but if i deselect something, it will give me text of that too.

Comment: This, as I understand what you're trying to do, will give a click event on each separate `option` (so you could do `$("#sizeAddCategory > option").click` and forget the class) - this isn't what OP is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

you write :

```
 var selected = $(e.target).text();
```

you should get the value of selectbox and
you should write

```
var selected = $(e.target).val();
```

Comment: `$(e.target).text()` gives all the text of options. `$(e.target).val()` and i dont need values

Answer (score 0):

oh my god
i right now understand what did you mean
ok

write :

```
$("#selectBox").change(function(e){

    var x = $(e.target).find("option:checked").text();

    console.log(x);
});
```