# how to get checked value from select multiple

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have implemented a customized select drop down menu with multiple checkboxes using a multiselect jquery. I'm trying to pass an array using ajax post after checking on the checboxes. When i clicked on the checkboxes, my jquery did not generate the array. Can someone help how i can get a array of checked value from the select drop down? Also the array should exclude the "Select all" checked boxes. Below is my code

This is how my drop down menu with check boxes looks like

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

/*********************convert select into multiselect************************/
$("#service").CreateMultiCheckBox({ width: '300px', defaultText : 'Select Below', height:'auto' }); 

    $("#service").on('change', function (){
                    var array = [];
                
                    $("#service option").each(function(){
                        if($(this).is(":checked"))
                        {array.push($(this).val());}    
                    }); 
                    
                    array = array.toString();   
                    alert(array);
                });
            
/**********************creating of checkboxes for each select option************************/
 $(document).on("click", ".MultiCheckBox", function () {
                var detail = $(this).next();
                detail.show();
            });

            $(document).on("click", ".MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader input", function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                var hc = $(this).prop("checked");
                $(this).closest(".MultiCheckBoxDetail").find(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody input").prop("checked", hc);
                $(this).closest(".MultiCheckBoxDetail").next().UpdateSelect();
            });

            $(document).on("click", ".MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader", function (e) {
                var inp = $(this).find("input");
                var chk = inp.prop("checked");
                inp.prop("checked", !chk);
                $(this).closest(".MultiCheckBoxDetail").find(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody input").prop("checked", !chk);
                $(this).closest(".MultiCheckBoxDetail").next().UpdateSelect();
            });

            $(document).on("click", ".MultiCheckBoxDetail .cont input", function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                $(this).closest(".MultiCheckBoxDetail").next().UpdateSelect();

                var val = ($(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody input:checked").length == $(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody input").length)
                $(".MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader input").prop("checked", val);
            });

            $(document).on("click", ".MultiCheckBoxDetail .cont", function (e) {
                var inp = $(this).find("input");
                var chk = inp.prop("checked");
                inp.prop("checked", !chk);

                var multiCheckBoxDetail = $(this).closest(".MultiCheckBoxDetail");
                var multiCheckBoxDetailBody = $(this).closest(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody");
                multiCheckBoxDetail.next().UpdateSelect();

                var val = ($(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody input:checked").length == $(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody input").length)
                $(".MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader input").prop("checked", val);
            });

            $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
                var container = $(".MultiCheckBoxDetail");
                if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
                    container.hide();
                }
            });
        });

        var defaultMultiCheckBoxOption = { width: '220px', defaultText: 'Select Below', height: '200px' };

        jQuery.fn.extend({
            CreateMultiCheckBox: function (options) {

                var localOption = {};
                localOption.width = (options != null && options.width != null && options.width != undefined) ? options.width : defaultMultiCheckBoxOption.width;
                localOption.defaultText = (options != null && options.defaultText != null && options.defaultText != undefined) ? options.defaultText : defaultMultiCheckBoxOption.defaultText;
                localOption.height = (options != null && options.height != null && options.height != undefined) ? options.height : defaultMultiCheckBoxOption.height;

                this.hide();
                this.attr("multiple", "multiple");
                var divSel = $("<div class='MultiCheckBox'>" + localOption.defaultText + "<span class='k-icon k-i-arrow-60-down'><svg aria-hidden='true' focusable='false' data-prefix='fas' data-icon='sort-down' role='img' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 320 512' class='svg-inline--fa fa-sort-down fa-w-10 fa-2x'><path fill='currentColor' d='M41 288h238c21.4 0 32.1 25.9 17 41L177 448c-9.4 9.4-24.6 9.4-33.9 0L24 329c-15.1-15.1-4.4-41 17-41z' class=''></path></svg></span></div>").insertBefore(this);
                divSel.css({ "width": localOption.width });

                var detail = $("<div class='MultiCheckBoxDetail'><div class='MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader'><input type='checkbox' class='mulinput' value='-1982' /><div>Select All</div></div><div class='MultiCheckBoxDetailBody'></div></div>").insertAfter(divSel);
                detail.css({ "width": parseInt(options.width) + 10, "max-height": localOption.height });
                var multiCheckBoxDetailBody = detail.find(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody");

                this.find("option").each(function () {
                    var val = $(this).attr("value");

                    if (val == undefined)
                        val = '';

                    multiCheckBoxDetailBody.append("<div class='cont'><div><input type='checkbox' class='mulinput' value='" + val + "' /></div><div>" + $(this).text() + "</div></div>");
                });

                multiCheckBoxDetailBody.css("max-height", (parseInt($(".MultiCheckBoxDetail").css("max-height")) - 28) + "px");
            },
            UpdateSelect: function () {
                var arr = [];

                this.prev().find(".mulinput:checked").each(function () {
                    arr.push($(this).val());
                });

                this.val(arr);
            },

});
```

```css
.MultiCheckBox {
            border:1px solid #e2e2e2;
            padding: 5px;
            border-radius:4px;
            cursor:pointer;
            background:#ffffff;
        }

        .MultiCheckBox .k-icon{ 
            font-size: 15px;
            float: right;
            font-weight: bolder;
            margin-top: -7px;
            height: 10px;
            width: 14px;
            color:#787878;
        } 

        .MultiCheckBoxDetail {
            display:none;
            position:absolute;
            border:1px solid #e2e2e2;
            overflow-y:hidden;
            background:#ffffff;
        }

        .MultiCheckBoxDetailBody {
            overflow-y:scroll;
        }

            .MultiCheckBoxDetail .cont  {
                clear:both;
                overflow: hidden;
                padding: 2px;
            }

            .MultiCheckBoxDetail .cont:hover  {
                background-color:#cfcfcf;
            }

            .MultiCheckBoxDetailBody > div > div {
                float:left;
            }

        .MultiCheckBoxDetail>div>div:nth-child(1) {
        
        }

        .MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader {
            overflow:hidden;
            position:relative;
            height: 28px;
            background-color:#3d3d3d;
        }

            .MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader>input {
                position: absolute;
                top: 4px;
                left: 3px;
            }

            .MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader>div {
                position: absolute;
                top: 5px;
                left: 24px;
                color:#fff;
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
                    <select name="service" class="service" id="service">
                        <option value = "'CONSTRUCTION'" >Construction</option>
                        <option value = "'HCL'" >HCL</option>
                        <option value = "'MANUFACTURING'" >Manufacturing</option>
                        <option value = "'MYE'" >MYE</option>
                        <option value = "'RSS'" >RSS</option>
                        <option value = "'SERVICE'" >SERVICE</option>
                        <option value = "'NA'" >NA</option>
                    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"get an array of checked values from a [multi] `select`"* - Does this answer your question? [How to get the selected text of options in multiple select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63613920/how-to-get-the-selected-text-of-options-in-multiple-select)

Comment: Change `$("#service").each(` to `$("#service option").each(`

Comment: @freedomn-m nope. its not working

Comment: @freedomn-m I have posted my code in the snippet. Please have a look. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in your code (three, but you fixed one after the comments, which is ok)

1. when you change an input's value via javascript, the `change` event does not fire, so you to need to add code to fire that event:

```
this.val(arr);
```

becomes

```
this.val(arr).change();
```

2. your data contains `'` - so when you attempt to build the HTML using string concat, you're actually not building what you expect

Instead of

```
<div value='val'>
```

you're creating:

```
<div value=''val''>
```

which gets parsed as

```
<div value='' val''>
```

or

```
<div value="" val"">
```

So `$(this).val() == undefined` and not `val`

Hopefully you can see that it's `value=""` then a separate `val''` - you could handle this by escaping quotes and switching `'` with `"` in various places, or, in the example below, remove it from the source:

```
  <option value="CONSTRUCTION">Construction</option>
```

Combined with `$("#select>option:checked")` (from `$("#select:checked")`) gives you:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

/*********************convert select into multiselect************************/
$("#service").CreateMultiCheckBox({ width: '300px', defaultText : 'Select Below', height:'auto' }); 

    $("#service").on('change', function (){
                    var array = [];
                
                    $("#service option").each(function(){
                        if($(this).is(":checked"))
                        {array.push($(this).val());}    
                    }); 
                    
                    array = array.toString();   
                    console.log(array);
                });
            
/**********************creating of checkboxes for each select option************************/
 $(document).on("click", ".MultiCheckBox", function () {
                var detail = $(this).next();
                detail.show();
            });

            $(document).on("click", ".MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader input", function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                var hc = $(this).prop("checked");
                $(this).closest(".MultiCheckBoxDetail").find(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody input").prop("checked", hc);
                $(this).closest(".MultiCheckBoxDetail").next().UpdateSelect();
            });

            $(document).on("click", ".MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader", function (e) {
                var inp = $(this).find("input");
                var chk = inp.prop("checked");
                inp.prop("checked", !chk);
                $(this).closest(".MultiCheckBoxDetail").find(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody input").prop("checked", !chk);
                $(this).closest(".MultiCheckBoxDetail").next().UpdateSelect();
            });

            $(document).on("click", ".MultiCheckBoxDetail .cont input", function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                $(this).closest(".MultiCheckBoxDetail").next().UpdateSelect();

                var val = ($(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody input:checked").length == $(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody input").length)
                $(".MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader input").prop("checked", val);
            });

            $(document).on("click", ".MultiCheckBoxDetail .cont", function (e) {
                var inp = $(this).find("input");
                var chk = inp.prop("checked");
                inp.prop("checked", !chk);

                var multiCheckBoxDetail = $(this).closest(".MultiCheckBoxDetail");
                var multiCheckBoxDetailBody = $(this).closest(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody");
                multiCheckBoxDetail.next().UpdateSelect();

                var val = ($(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody input:checked").length == $(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody input").length)
                $(".MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader input").prop("checked", val);
            });

            $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
                var container = $(".MultiCheckBoxDetail");
                if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
                    container.hide();
                }
            });
        });

        var defaultMultiCheckBoxOption = { width: '220px', defaultText: 'Select Below', height: '200px' };

        jQuery.fn.extend({
            CreateMultiCheckBox: function (options) {

                var localOption = {};
                localOption.width = (options != null && options.width != null && options.width != undefined) ? options.width : defaultMultiCheckBoxOption.width;
                localOption.defaultText = (options != null && options.defaultText != null && options.defaultText != undefined) ? options.defaultText : defaultMultiCheckBoxOption.defaultText;
                localOption.height = (options != null && options.height != null && options.height != undefined) ? options.height : defaultMultiCheckBoxOption.height;

                this.hide();
                this.attr("multiple", "multiple");
                var divSel = $("<div class='MultiCheckBox'>" + localOption.defaultText + "<span class='k-icon k-i-arrow-60-down'><svg aria-hidden='true' focusable='false' data-prefix='fas' data-icon='sort-down' role='img' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 320 512' class='svg-inline--fa fa-sort-down fa-w-10 fa-2x'><path fill='currentColor' d='M41 288h238c21.4 0 32.1 25.9 17 41L177 448c-9.4 9.4-24.6 9.4-33.9 0L24 329c-15.1-15.1-4.4-41 17-41z' class=''></path></svg></span></div>").insertBefore(this);
                divSel.css({ "width": localOption.width });

                var detail = $("<div class='MultiCheckBoxDetail'><div class='MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader'><input type='checkbox' class='mulinput' value='-1982' /><div>Select All</div></div><div class='MultiCheckBoxDetailBody'></div></div>").insertAfter(divSel);
                detail.css({ "width": parseInt(options.width) + 10, "max-height": localOption.height });
                var multiCheckBoxDetailBody = detail.find(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody");

                this.find("option").each(function () {
                    var val = $(this).attr("value");

                    if (val == undefined)
                        val = '';

                    multiCheckBoxDetailBody.append("<div class='cont'><div><input type='checkbox' class='mulinput' value='" + val + "' /></div><div>" + $(this).text() + "</div></div>");
                });

                multiCheckBoxDetailBody.css("max-height", (parseInt($(".MultiCheckBoxDetail").css("max-height")) - 28) + "px");
            },
            UpdateSelect: function () {
                var arr = [];

                this.prev().find(".mulinput:checked").each(function () {
                    arr.push($(this).val());
                });

                this.val(arr).change();
            },

});
```

```css
.MultiCheckBox {
            border:1px solid #e2e2e2;
            padding: 5px;
            border-radius:4px;
            cursor:pointer;
            background:#ffffff;
        }

        .MultiCheckBox .k-icon{ 
            font-size: 15px;
            float: right;
            font-weight: bolder;
            margin-top: -7px;
            height: 10px;
            width: 14px;
            color:#787878;
        } 

        .MultiCheckBoxDetail {
            display:none;
            position:absolute;
            border:1px solid #e2e2e2;
            overflow-y:hidden;
            background:#ffffff;
        }

        .MultiCheckBoxDetailBody {
            overflow-y:scroll;
        }

            .MultiCheckBoxDetail .cont  {
                clear:both;
                overflow: hidden;
                padding: 2px;
            }

            .MultiCheckBoxDetail .cont:hover  {
                background-color:#cfcfcf;
            }

            .MultiCheckBoxDetailBody > div > div {
                float:left;
            }

        .MultiCheckBoxDetail>div>div:nth-child(1) {
        
        }

        .MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader {
            overflow:hidden;
            position:relative;
            height: 28px;
            background-color:#3d3d3d;
        }

            .MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader>input {
                position: absolute;
                top: 4px;
                left: 3px;
            }

            .MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader>div {
                position: absolute;
                top: 5px;
                left: 24px;
                color:#fff;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="service" class="service" id="service">
  <option value="CONSTRUCTION">Construction</option>
  <option value="HCL">HCL</option>
  <option value="MANUFACTURING">Manufacturing</option>
  <option value="MYE">MYE</option>
  <option value="RSS">RSS</option>
  <option value="SERVICE">SERVICE</option>
  <option value="NA">NA</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say

```
$("#service option:selected").each(function(){
//Do stuff Here
});
```

If you wants to see more :
https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

If i use your code it would be :

```
var array = []
$("#service option").each(function(){
                        if($(this).is(":selected"))
                        {array.push($(this).val());}    
                    });
```

Comment: I have already tried that. The checked value doesn't seem to pass to jquery array